# PHP Session doesnt start when I uploaded site to server

Tags: php, session, server

Locally everything works. SQL Queries, login, editing. But when I uploaded on a server, i can still get content out of sql, it succeeds to login, but it doesnt start SESSION. I am still logged out.

http://www.klemen-lozar.com/

Where can I see the error happening or whatever is wrong?

Comment: Code for logging in would be a good place to start.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8u0im4

Comment: Don't post a *screenshot* of your code.. Post the relevant code directly in your question. But why have you commented out `session_start();`

Comment: Tried different things, it made no difference, I will enable it again. I didnt post code in question because maybe its not a code issue if it works locally...

Comment: Nevermind, that fixed it... But it didnt work before, thats why I commented it in the first place